# google chrome keep giving error in caught TypeError even though the element matches the html element

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "active";

}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale" style="width: 100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width: 100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale" style="width: 100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>


<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
at showSlides (sam.js:25:26)
at sam.js:2:1
5sam.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')
at showSlides (sam.js:26:9)
at plusSlides (sam.js:5:5)
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM229 index.html:1:1)
```

I tired to change the class name and delete the style tag in javascript the part of the line it saying it causing issue. i thought might be css and so i mess with css that causing it but it still giving that error message and some time when refresh the browser there are no image displaying and when i hit next arrow it activates the images and able to click next and change images but somehow it give that error and the images wont display load up when load the website first time or hitting refresh

Comment: I added a further suggestion to improve slide show UX (user experience) if you like to apply it in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution, when adding a new class using as a string, make sure you separate them by space in `dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";`. Also, you didn't check if `slideIndex` is less than `1` and I added this condition in the `showSlides(n)` function.

One Suggestion for your code:

- When the user reaches the end of the slides, generally it's better if you made him remain at the final slide instead of returning him back to the first slide, so that he know he reached the end and don't keep scrolling not knowing he reached the end except after observing he has same images repeating.
  That's why I edited this line of code

```
if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = n -1;
  }
```

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}


function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = n -1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  console.log("SlideIndex", slideIndex)

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";



}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="./images/insidelook1.jpeg" style="width: 100%">


  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="./images/insidelook2.jpeg" style="width: 100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="./images/insidelook4.jpeg" style="width: 100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>


<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

These two operations are doing more than you think:

```
dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
// and...
dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "active";
```

By changing the entire text of the `className` (*and* changing it in a way you might not have intended, note the lack of a space character in the result...), you're effectively modifying the [live HTML collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) result of this:

```
let dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
```

Which means the *length* of that collection changes.  You can observe this by logging some debugging information to the console:

```
console.log('dots length: ', dots.length);
dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "active";
```

Instead of directly replacing the `className` property, make use of [the `classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
dots[i].classList.remove("active");
// and...
dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
```

This will allow the rest of the classes to remain unaffected, which in turn won't affect the `HTMLCollection` object over which you're iterating.